# inheritance in a UIView file

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Simple question about inheritance

I have a standard program with a master view:

**MasterViewController.h**

`enter code here`@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController

using a subview for drawing:

**MasterViewController.m**

```
frame = CGRectMake(xo, yo,  side*width, side*height);   // maxSide
backView = [[BackView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self infoToBackView];
[self.view addSubview:backView];
```

**BackView.h**

```
@interface BackView : UIView
```

and **BackView.m** has its drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect {
    :
    :
}
```

The problem I have is that I want BackView to inherit from MasterViewController, i.e. I want
Backview.h to be

```
@interface BackView : MasterViewController
```

which allows it to inherit the variables it needs from MasterViewController.

The problem is that this does not work; BackView must inherit from UIView to be able to draw with DrawRect. Therefore, before calling the UIView BackView, I must send it the variables it needs for drawing:

```
[self infoToBackView];
[backView setNeedsDisplay];
```

where infoToBackView is a method sending the needed variables to BackView.

The $64,000 question: How can I have a BackView that inherits from MasterViewController AND has drawRect?

Comment: You can't do this because Objective-C doesn't have multiple inheritance. You shouldn't do this because a view controller is not a view. You'd be better off thinking about the design a little more. You don't need to inherit variables from the view controller - the view controller should be using that information and passing it to the view.

Comment: You can't.  If your view is going to draw itself, it needs to be a UIView subclass.  Why is it a problem to pass the values to the view?

Comment: It's NOT a problem to pass values to the view. I just thought that using inheritance would make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

BackView is a View, it is design to DRAW something.
ViewController are design to manage a view Herarchy.

They are not the same things. One is a plane, the other is an aiport! You cannot fly an airport...
UIView's subclass are design to draw. If you want to draw (text, shapes..) on screen, create a subclass of UIView. If you want to manage a scene in your app storyboard, create a subclass of UIViewController.

`drawRect:` is a method of UIView

Now you can pass variable to your view from your viewController, like a label (another kind of View) received a text to know what to display.

For example in your ViewController, you can have:

```
self.myBackView.color = [UIColor blueColor];
self.myBackView.progress = .5;
self.myBackView.text = @"MVC is awesome";
```

For a better understanding of the MVC design pattern, please reffer to Apple doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html